# Facebook login in Swift 3

Tags: swift, facebook, swift3, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hi I'm having a problem with FBLogin in `Swift` 
It always displays

> "User cancelled login."

in `iOS8.2` 
and

> "Falling back to storing access token in `NSUserDefaults` because of simulator bug"

when I use `iOS10.1`

Do you have any suggestions regarding this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by adding these functions in my AppDelegate.swift

```
 @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

         return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation] as Any
         )
    }

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

Hope will help

Comment: You also can look here to fix deprecated warning https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/35